# Plugin files/database doesn't appear using wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am facing very strange issue, I have installed a wordpress plugin (Google maps delevoped by webdorado) into the wordpress via web (dashboard) and everything works just fine as it should.

The problem that I am facing is that I cannot find nether plugin's files (directories) in the "wp-content/plugins" folder where all plugins should be held, nether its databases in "phpmyadmin" which is very strange.

The other plugins installed on the website - their files and databases are in "wp-content/plugins" as well as in the database which is how they should be, but the Google maps plugin is not in the "wp-content/plugins" folder nether in the database. I have installed the plugin on the other hosting and domain to test it out if the files appear there and in fact files did appear with databases as they should, but on my original domain database and files are not shown for some reason - but the plugin works and I can use the plugin just as fine.

Mainly, I am wondering why cant I see the files and databases of the Google maps plugin?

Extra notices, I am using "Filezilla" ftp solution to access the files and phpmyadmin to check the database's content.
I am really thinking there might be an issue with permissions that are blocking the "view" of the "Google maps" plugin's files.

Thanks!

Comment: tell me the plugin name please

Comment: @HassanALi hey there, it would be Google Map plugin by webdorado. I am supposing there might be an issue with permissions, right?

Comment: Give us some context, you have given us too little information to work with. Learn to create a [mcve] (internal link).

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC updated!

Comment: @SvaikaAndriu Please put a quote in "Im" and capitalize your "i"'s. And files ≠ directories.